# Multiprocessing : Pool in a yield 'sandwich' behaves like a single process

Tags: python, multiprocessing, generator, cpu-usage, yield

the following is taking the same time as single process !! Also I dont see the CPUs working hard as in the other cases

```
def get_line(fileobj):
        for line in fileobj:
            yield line

 def blah(self,file,..):
    ........   
    with open(file,'r') as file:
      with Pool(processes=nworkers) as pool :
         res = pool.imap_unordered(EXPENSIVE_PROCESS, get_line(file), chunksize=5)
         for pp in res :
           if pp is not None : yield res
```

and this is then used like this :

```
  for x in obj.blah() :
      ........
```

Is the reason because it is sandwiched between two YIELDS or I'm doing something wrong !!

It is passing string line in and is returning  a List or None

And ofcource how to solve it ?

BTW I have to keep get_line generator cause i also have get_paragraph and i will use them depending on the case

---

After further testing it seems slightly faster ! so probably the EXPENSIVE process is not expensive enough to compensate for shuffling of lines between processes !

have to generate more data to see if i get bigger difference

Comment: I created a test where on my desktop EXPENSIVE_PROCESS took approximately .5 seconds of CPU. Running against a file of 64 lines with a single process took the expected 30 seconds. With a pool size of 8 (the number of logical cores I have) and other "stuff" running on my machine, the running time became 8.8 seconds. For this number of tasks (64), a chunksize of 1 actually ran faster (8.1 seconds).